# Уменьшить нагрузку на сервер(ы) при выполнении цикла с file_get_contents() и preg_match()

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Имеется парсер цен на РНР:

```
foreach ($products as $product){
    ...
    $pageContent = file_get_contents($sourcePageURL);
    preg_match('/<'.$openedTagWithClass.'>'(.*?)<\\/'.$openedTag.'>/is', $pageContent, $priceString);
    $priceFromLink = $priceString[1];
    ...
}
```

В массиве `$products` каждый элемент содержит ссылку на страницу с источником цены и открывающий тег с классом. Т.е. `file_get_contents()` берет содержимое страницы по ссылке, а `preg_match()` вытягивает с него только цену между указанными тегами.

Пока что на входе массив содержит немного страниц, но со временем планируется несколько сотень поэтому интересует вопрос: как можно минимизировать нагрузку на сайты-источники или их сервера при выполнении данного процесса?

Может как то разбивать весь цикл на части или как, не ориентируюсь глубоко что на самом деле происходит, в общем нужно как то оптимизировать данный процесс если на входе будут сотни страниц.

Answer (score 2):

`file_get_contents()` это то же HTTP-запрос. Если сайт-источник отдаёт `Last-Modified`, то хороший вариант - обрабатывать это.

1. Где-то у себя сохраняете информацию вида `URL => Last-Modified`
2. Используете не `file_get_contents()`, а непосредственно HTTP-запрос (как - тут много вариантов, например, `curl`), с HTTP-заголовком `If-Modified-Since: значение_для_этого_URL`.
3. Если получили `HTTP 304`, то ничего не делаем, информация не изменилась.
4. Получили что-то другое - обрабатываем и сохраняем новое значение времени модификации в базе.

Ещё можно ввести паузы между запросами.

Всё остальное происходит на вашей стороне, поэтому на сайт-источник никак повлиять не может (а если он начнёт блокировать вас - это уже совсем другая тема).

Comment: К стати, употребляет ли curl меньше памяти чем file_get_contents? (независимо от того о памяти какого сервера идет речь: моего или сервера сайта-источника)

Comment: @stckvrw происходящее на вашей стороне никак не может ничего потреблять на сайте-источнике. Ему всё равно чем вы запрашиваете. Про потребление памяти не знаю, меряйте.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы будете продолжать в том же духе, то наткнетесь [вот на это](https://ergonotes.ru/7-sposobov-zashhitit-sayt-ot-parsinga-i-kak-ih-oboyti/) 
Основываясь на собственном опыте и руководствуясь [статьей по оптимизации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/134784/)
я вижу что ваш код жрет слишком много оперативной памяти, ввиду того что вы используете регулярные выражения ко всему объему информации
1 что может потреблять память - если в этом цикле идет присвоение к массиву, то это выносится за цикл ссылкой вот так

```
$save_memory=&$arr;//добавлено с целью оптимизации памяти в икле
foreach ($products as &$product){
    ...
    $arr[]=$some_sing;
    ...
    $pageContent = file_get_contents($sourcePageURL);
    preg_match('/<'.$openedTagWithClass.'>'(.*?)<\\/'.$openedTag.'>/is', $pageContent, $priceString);
    $priceFromLink = $priceString[1];
    ...
    unset($pageContent,$product);
}
```

Во вторых избавиться от регулярных выражений

```
    $reader = new XMLReader();
    $save_memory=&$arr;//добавлено с целью оптимизации памяти в икле
    foreach ($products as &$product){
        ...
        $arr[]=$some_sing;
        ...
        $pageContent = file_get_contents($sourcePageURL);
        $reader->open($pageContent); // указываем ридеру что будем парсить этот файл
        while($reader->read()) {
           if($reader->localName == $openedTag 
              && $reader->getAttribute('class') == 'искомый класс')
           {
              //$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($reader->readString);
              //$priceFromLink = $movies->{$openedTag};
              $priceFromLink = $reader->readString;
           }
        }

        ...
        unset($pageContent,$product);
    }
```

поправьте меня в строке

```
 $priceFromLink = $reader->readString;
```

Есть еще вариант - это [phpQuery](https://habrahabr.ru/post/69149/)

Comment: А каким образом всё это относится к снижению нагрузки на сайты-источники?

Comment: @PinkTux снижать нагрузку можно только на своем сервере. Снижать нагрузку на другие серверы можно лишь при помощи одно команды usleep(10000); Либо договориться с ними о создании api

Comment: Во-первых, не только (см. мой ответ), во-вторых, я в курсе. Спрашиваю про другое: какое отношение ваш ответ имеет к вопросу?

Comment: Да, верно: интересует как снизить нагрузку на серверы сайтов-источников, а не на мой сервер, обновляю цены на локалке

Comment: @Mcile, по поводу ридера, то дело в том что сайты-источники разные и у них цена содержится внутри разных тегов с разными атрибутами: классами, айди, data- и т.д. Поэтому `$reader->getAttribute('class') == 'искомый класс'` здесь не подходит. Нужен более гибкий метод, чтобы можно было указать любые атрибуты к хтмл-тегу и в любом порядке например `div class="product-price" id="price"`. Кроме того внутри тега, но еще ПЕРЕД самой ценой, может быть какой то повторяющийся текст например `<div class="product-price" id="price">Цена: 100 у.е.</div>` (т.е. повторяется слово "Цена")